# Reducing wind noise inside

Tags: windows, noise-reduction, wind

Living in suburbs west of Denver, we sometimes have rather windy nights. Tonight it's blowing about 25mph from the west, which means mostly parallel to my bedroom window.

The windows are about 12 years old, double pane, and still well sealed as far as I can tell. However, when the wind gets blowing it's easily loud enough to wake us. Most of the house really just seems to be air movement; not things outside going bump in the night.

I'll remove the screen on the windier nights, which helps somewhat. Any other suggestions to reduce the wind noise through the window?

Comment: share a photo. Might help understand what kind of siding, how it was installed, etc.

Comment: Plant a wind break? Any disruption to straight line wind reduces its force, which I assume is causing the noise. If the noise is whistling or howling, then better sealing and insulation is called for.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience there are several common sources of sound caused by the wind at a window.

1. Banging screen. The screen is loose and the wind rattles it back and forth in the frame. To test, removed it and see if the noise goes away. To fix, put something in the track to hold the screen tight. Just about anything will work including a stick, or a piece of foam, such as a piece of door weather sealing foam
2. Banging glass / the window slider. Very similar to the screen issue but for the opening side of the window, especially for a slider window. You don't want to remove it to test like the screen but you can test with the fix noted for the screen. Shim it tight and see if the noise changes
3. Whistling. This is usually about the shape of the house or a part of it, which can be the edge of the window frame or trim. You might need to go outside to investigate and narrow down the source. Likely sources include anything with a sharp edge (think of blowing over the lip of a bottle as a musical instrument). Changing the shape of the edge will change the sound until its gone. Use something appropriate, whether it is a new piece of trim, sanding the edge, or so on

Answer (score 0):

Try listening around the window to see where the noise is loudest. It can help to use a piece of mid-size tubing (maybe 3/8 to 3/4 inch diameter) as a stethoscope of sorts. Hold one end firmly to the ear and probe around the window with the other end. Sounds will be carried through the tubing and you'll be able to localize them better. Listen around the woodwork/casing around the window too, not just points on the window unit itself.

I'll guess that there's not a lot you can do about sound which transmits through the glass. The seal between the movable pane and the fixed pane is a likely place for sound to enter, and this one you may be able to easily improve. If the window is opened never, seldom, or even just seasonally, then foam (weatherstrip) pressed into the gap or tape applied over the gap could help. Watch out not to damage the brush/seal that's already in that space.

You might also be able to determine whether noise is created right there at the window. That removal of the screen helps suggests this could be the case. Experiment in that area a little more. For example, try fitting open cell foam in the space between the screen and the glass on windy nights. Something like a camping mat -- thin foam might be found at a craft store. It'll prevent the screen from vibrating, and it may reduce the noise of wind swirling around the edges in that space. Another experiment to try is externally applied shrink film (find it with other weatherization products in a home center). That may help the air currents to pass by the window with less turbulence. The film would need some support in the middle (the foam would do) to prevent it flapping and vibrating, especially if the window is large.

Also look/listen in other places -- sometimes wind noise comes through wall penetrations for electrical and low-voltage outlets or other unexpected places.